# Direct TCP connection to Heroku application

Tags: java, heroku, tcp, serversocket

I have a Spring Application with several REST endpoint running on Heroku on port 8888. It works correctly and the base url is something like `xxx.herokuapp.com`.

Now I added a TCP server to my application on port 6666 by using `java.net.ServerSocket`. I can reach it locally with `netcat localhost 6666 <SampleRequest.txt` and it works properly.

How can I send a direct TCP request to the application deployed on Heroku?

I'd like to have other clients (not on my machine) to contact the TCP server on Heroku. Such clients do not implement HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Heroku Exec](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec) feature with a command like `heroku ps:forward 6666`

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me. I gave the command you shared to forward, but TCP connection still times out when giving netcat xxxxx.herokuapp.com 6666 <SampleRequest.txt.

Comment: When using `heroku ps:forward` you'll only be able to connect to `localhost:6666`

Comment: So all clients will be required heroku on their side, which unfortunately is not the case...